# No sound on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, 64-bit, pulseaudio, alsa

As the title, I'm getting no sound on Ubuntu 14.04; sound are correctly reproduced on Windows.
I've tried many solutions, but the problem seems to be that pulseaudio doesn't recognize my sound card.
Maybe this is due to some changes that I've done in bootup services, even if I don't think I changed something related to audio devices.

This is the services current running

```
$>sudo service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apache2
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ + ]  bumblebeed
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ + ]  ddclient
 [ + ]  dictd
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  ebtables
 [ - ]  fancontrol
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hddtemp
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ + ]  libvirt-bin
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ - ]  lm-sensors
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ + ]  nmbd
 [ + ]  ntop
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ - ]  postgresql
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  qemu-system-x86
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ ? ]  runhwactivator
 [ + ]  samba
 [ - ]  samba-ad-dc
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ - ]  smartmontools
 [ + ]  smbd
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ ? ]  tlp
 [ - ]  tomcat7
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ ? ]  vboxautostart-service
 [ + ]  vboxballoonctrl-service
 [ + ]  vboxdrv
 [ + ]  vboxweb-service
 [ + ]  winbind
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

I noticed that many of the services flagged as [ - ] actually are active; so, I don't know if this output is true. As you can see, it seems that pulseaudio is not running. However

```
$>sudo service pulseaudio status
pulseaudio start/running, process 7993
```

Btw, here are some screenshots.

alsamixer
[image: alsamixer output]

some pulseaudio tabs while reproducing some sounds[image: Playback tab]
[image]

Other tabs are simply empty, so it seems that it doesn't correctly recognize my sound card. Any idea?

Comment: The solution proposed by @laugeo works very well for me.
To tell the truth, there are other solutions [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , reset pulseaudio configuration by copying this command in a terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

If not ok, try to disable pulseaudio by running these 2 commands in  a terminal:

```
echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
sudo killall -9 pulseaudio
```

then run

```
pulseaudio
```

to relaunch audio apps and test.
Almost all Linux audio programs can use only Alsa without Pulseaudio (except Skype).

To set alsa volume easier than Alsamixer, install `gnome-alsamixer`.

Comment: Well, it works in some way; at least, until I reboot the system.
After the `sudo killall` coomand, I have to manually run `pulseaudio` from a terminal to see the right input/output devices.
Wnen I restart the session, btw, these devices disappear again and I have to do all the procedure again.

Comment: So  try to run `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf` to autolaunch pulseaudio as before and test after reboot

Comment: thanks, now it works ;) Just another question: why if I run `sudo service status pulseaudio` it tells that the service is stopped?

Comment: Yes because pulseaudio is not runned as a service(it could be for some special use),  but as a user program (starting when user logon).

Answer (score -3):

first go to your pc/laptop co. site then download your drivers for pc/laptop then install it .
restart/reboot your system via terminal ctrl+alt+t
type : reboot -f
Done                                                              :-)

Comment: How to install it? Nobody knows.

Comment: Please elaborate the process to install it